# why i am getting error in my get call using spring bootstrao

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to create an update method using spring bootstrap but it is giving me error in get.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file", method = GET)
```

I am getting file path not found /file/upload/

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/file", method = GET)
public class FileResource {

    // define a location
    public static final String DIRECTORY = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads/";

    // method for upload
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> uploadFiles(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull @RequestParam("files")List<MultipartFile> MultipartFile) throws IOException {
        List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MultipartFile file : MultipartFile) {
            String filename = StringUtils.cleanPath(Objects.requireNonNull(file.getOriginalFilename()));
            Path fileStorage = get(DIRECTORY, filename).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
            copy(file.getInputStream(), fileStorage, REPLACE_EXISTING);
            filenames.add(filename);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(filenames);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `FileResource` is your controller, you shouldn't put `method = GET` at your `@RequestMapping`. Remove it and try to send a POST again

Hope it will help

Comment: I removed it still have the same error